# Populating class from json data

Tags: objective-c, arrays, json, class, sendasynchronousrequest

I have a WCF that returns some json data in the format of:

```
{
"RetrieveLocationsResult": [
   {
        "Address": "106 Mullaghboy Road",
        "Category": "Tarmac",
        "Closest_Property_Number": 106,
        "ID": 33,
        "Image1": 1234,
        "Image2": 0,
        "Image3": 0,
        "Latitude": 5,
        "Longitude": "-1.541902",
        "Notes": "New Driveway",
        "User_ID": 1
    },
    {
        "Address": "3 drumard road",
        "Category": "Tarmac",
        "Closest_Property_Number": 3,
        "ID": 40,
        "Image1": 23421,
        "Image2": 0,
        "Image3": 0,
        "Latitude": 4,
        "Longitude": "-2.541902",
        "Notes": "new gates",
        "User_ID": 1
    },
]
}
```

This can be seen here in full http://crm.fpmccann.co.uk/TemperatureWebService/iphonewebservice.svc/retrievelocations

I have a class called location with each variable made up. What I want to do is parse this json data into each location, sort of make an array of locations which are going to be placed on a map using the longitude and latitude.

My method for parsing the data so far is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

     NSString *urlAsString = @"http://crm.fpmccann.co.uk/TemperatureWebService/iphonewebservice.svc/retrievelocations";
     NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlAsString];
     NSURLRequest *urlRequest = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

     [NSURLConnection
      sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest
      queue:[[NSOperationQueue alloc] init]
      completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response,
                          NSData *data,
                          NSError *error)

      {
          NSLog(@"error: %@", error);
          NSLog(@"data: %@", data);
          NSLog(@"response: %@", response);

          if ([data length] >0 && error == nil)
          {
              NSArray *array = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data
                                                               options:0
                                                                 error:&error];
              NSLog(@"Response: %@", array);

              CLLocationCoordinate2D location;                         // coordinates of the annotation
              NSMutableArray *newAnnotations = [NSMutableArray array]; // an array in which we'll save our annotations temporarily
              MKPointAnnotation *newAnnotation;                        // the pointer to the annotation we're adding

              NSMutableArray *location = [array valueForKey:@"RetrieveLocationsResult"];


              NSMutableArray *longitude = [[array valueForKey:@"RetrieveLocationsResult"] valueForKey:@"Longitude"];


             // NSLog(@"Response", response, data);
          }
          else if ([data length] == 0 && error == nil)
          {
              NSLog(@"Nothing was downloaded.");
          }
          else if (error != nil){
              NSLog(@"Error = %@", error);
          }

      }];


}
```

Please excuse that this is in the view did load, this will be changed as soon as its working.
It is creating and array called location, there is 4 objects in it but there is nothing in them. What I want to do is create a for loop and populate a class based on the results?

Comment: Create an `initWIthDictionary:(NSDictionary*)dict` method for your location class and have it read the dictionary and set the object fields.  This can be "automated" to a degree, using "key/value coding", if the values are all simple and the field names match the dictionary keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create a JSON Dictionary for Retrieved results:

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:nil];
NSMutableArray *retrieveLocationsResultArr = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:[jsonDict objectForKey:@"RetrieveLocationsResult"]];

[retrieveLocationsResultArr enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *locationDict, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    //Create your Location Objects
    NSString *addressStr = [locationDict valueForKey:@"Address"];//sample, extract all values you want in your custom objects.
}];
```

Comment: Can you please explain this part of the code a bit better to me please and thank you [retrieveLocationsResultArr enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSDictionary *locationDict, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
    //Create your Location Objects
    NSString *addressStr = [locationDict valueForKey:@"Address"];//sample, extract all values you want in your custom objects.
}];